# Can R automatically recognize and count the number of occurrences of a word in n number of columns?

Tags: r

This is something of a heavy question, but I will try to do my best to explain. I am trying to write a program that tracks how many times an insect has visited a species of flower over time. To do this, I have a data set that looks something like this:

```
ID          Visit_Freq   Visitor_1   Visitor_2   Visitor_3   Visitor_4   Visitor_5
1             1.0000000  Halictidae       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>
2             5.0000000  Syrphidae Halictidae  Syrphidae  Syrphidae       Apis
3             1.0000000        Apis       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>
4             0.0000000        <NA>       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>
5             0.0000000        <NA>       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>
6             0.0000000        <NA>       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>
7             0.0000000        <NA>       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>
8             2.0000000        Apis       Apis       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>
9             0.0000000        <NA>       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>
10            0.0000000        <NA>       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>
```

Under the "Visitor_n" columns, I have recorded a type of insect that has visited that flower, or an NA for no visits. To analyze our data, we have to count every occurrence of an insect type throughout the Visitor columns. Sometimes we can have as many as 10 visitors to a flower (ID), and we often have an ID count of over 500, so counting the occurrences by hand can be a chore. Here is what I have done to make it easier:

```
Apis <- sum(apply(DataSet[3:7], 2, function(x) length(which(x == 'Apis'))))
```

So far, that line above has worked well to count the number of times that Apis occurs in my real data set, but the problem is that there are literally dozens of insect types that may or may not visit our plants, so to be safe, I would have to have about 30-50 similar lines of code, each replacing "Apis" with a different insect type... for example...

```
Apis <- sum(apply(DataSet[3:7], 2, function(x) length(which(x == 'Apis'))))
Bombus <- sum(apply(DataSet[3:7], 2, function(x) length(which(x == 'Bombus'))))
Halictidae <- sum(apply(DataSet[3:7], 2, function(x) length(which(x == 'Halictidae'))))
Syrphidae <- sum(apply(DataSet[3:7], 2, function(x) length(which(x == 'Syrphidae'))))
Skipper <- sum(apply(DataSet[3:7], 2, function(x) length(which(x == 'Skipper'))))
```

etc., etc.

It would be really helpful if I could find a way to make R automatically recognize that "Insects A, B, D, F, and H appear in columns [3:7], and here are the number of times that they all occur", for example, rather than having to type out 30-50 lines of every insect to make sure that I am not missing anything.

I'm not against installing packages to do this, but I would like to keep it as close to base R as possible, if possible. I'd like to introduce this to some lab mates of mine who have little to no R experience.

I did ask a similar question last night, but I have made some advances since then.

Comment: `table(unlist(DataSet[, grep('Visitor', names(DataSet))]))`?

Comment: The fundamental problem you're encountering is that your data are not tidy. You should really have only 4 columns, ID, Visit_Freq, Visitor_Number, Species. Then, in this format, what you want to do is easy using functions such as `summarize` or `tally` in dplyr.

If you can post code that generates a data frame of the type you're dealing with then I'm happy to show how to rearrange it into tidy form and then summarize.

Comment: @ClausWilke how is this not "tidy?" this is what we in the industry commonly refer to as a "wide" format. There is a "wide" format and a "long" format. You seem to be implying that a "long" format is "tidy" and thus "correct." Perhaps if one's skill set only lies within the hadley universe, then yeah it would be better to use a long format, but let's not advise people to limit themselves in that way, okay?

Comment: @rawr Here, "tidy" is a technical term, as defined in Wickham's paper. That doesn't have anything to do with whether the format is correct or not. Clearly both long and wide tables contain the same information, so are equally correct. However, in many cases, analyses are much simpler on the long form, simply because we have better tools for working with long tables than with wide tables. Also, in this particular case, where the number of visitors is not known a priori, a wide table seems a particularly bad choice, leading to huge numbers of NAs.

Comment: @ClausWilke-- I certainly wouldn't mind that. I am currently in the middle of nowhere and have little to no internet access a lot of the time, so it might be a little bit hard for me to get back to everyone. I appreciate everyone's answers, they were all insightful.

Answer (score 3):

This solution assumes that your insect names have only English alphabets and no numerals and the first letter is upper case and remainings are lower case.

```
data.frame(table(grep("[A-Z]{1}[a-z]+",stack(df1)[,1],value=TRUE)))
        Var1 Freq
1       Apis    4
2 Halictidae    2
3  Syrphidae    3
```

## Data

```
df1<-
structure(list(ID = 1:10, Visit_Freq = c(1, 5, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
2, 0, 0), Visitor_1 = c("Halictidae", "Syrphidae", "Apis", "<NA>", 
"<NA>", "<NA>", "<NA>", "Apis", "<NA>", "<NA>"), Visitor_2 = c("<NA>", 
"Halictidae", "<NA>", "<NA>", "<NA>", "<NA>", "<NA>", "Apis", 
"<NA>", "<NA>"), Visitor_3 = c("<NA>", "Syrphidae", "<NA>", "<NA>", 
"<NA>", "<NA>", "<NA>", "<NA>", "<NA>", "<NA>"), Visitor_4 = c("<NA>", 
"Syrphidae", "<NA>", "<NA>", "<NA>", "<NA>", "<NA>", "<NA>", 
"<NA>", "<NA>"), Visitor_5 = c("<NA>", "Apis", "<NA>", "<NA>", 
"<NA>", "<NA>", "<NA>", "<NA>", "<NA>", "<NA>")), .Names = c("ID", 
"Visit_Freq", "Visitor_1", "Visitor_2", "Visitor_3", "Visitor_4", 
"Visitor_5"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1):

Just create a vector with our insect names

```
insects <- c( "Apis", "Halictidae", "Syrphidae" )
```

You also could obtain this automatically with

```
insects <- unique( unlist( DataSet[ 3:7 ] ) )
insects <- insects[ -( which ( insects == "<NA>" ) ) ]
```

Then create an empty variable that takes the visit counts

```
count <- NULL
```

then you can stay with what you have and just loop through the insect names

```
for( i in insects ) 
    count <- c( count, sum( apply( DataSet[ 3:7 ], 2, 
                       function( x ) length( which( x == i) ) ) ) )
count
[1] 4 2 3
```

If you want to, you can combine the two

```
insectCount <- data.frame( insects, count )
insectCount
     insects count
1       Apis     4
2 Halictidae     2
3  Syrphidae     3
```

Please note that the order of insects will be different depending upon whether you create the vector manually or automatically. The count will be the same in either case.

Answer (score 0):

I like `dplyr` for these kinds of questions, because the problem can literally be solved in one line, once the data are in the correct (tidy) format. To convert the data into tidy format, we need one more line (using `gather()` from package `tidyr`).

I'm using the data frame that user227710 defined [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31237592/4975218) Note that it contains strings "<NA>" instead of proper R NAs, so the line that filters out the NAs looks a bit weird.

The actual work is done by the functions `group_by()` and `tally()`. You tell R how the data should be grouped (here by the `Species` variable), and then `tally()` counts them.

And I understand, you didn't want to use external packages, but learning how to use `tidyr` and `dplyr` is absolutely worth it for anybody who wrangles data on a regular basis.

```
require(tidyr) # for gather()
require(dplyr) # for group_by() and tally()

# convert table into tidy (long) format
df_long <- gather(df1, Visitor, Species, Visitor_1:Visitor_5)
head(df_long)
##   ID Visit_Freq   Visitor    Species
## 1  1          1 Visitor_1 Halictidae
## 2  2          5 Visitor_1  Syrphidae
## 3  3          1 Visitor_1       Apis
## 4  4          0 Visitor_1       <NA>
## 5  5          0 Visitor_1       <NA>
## 6  6          0 Visitor_1       <NA>

# now count species, excluding the <NA> value
group_by(df_long, Species) %>%
    filter(Species != "<NA>") %>% 
    tally()
## Source: local data frame [3 x 2]
## 
##      Species  n
## 2       Apis  4
## 3 Halictidae  2
## 4  Syrphidae  3
```